# How to run two times in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am new in swiftUI, and I know how to do it in Xcode to make two different random "a" and "b",and print the output. However, I do not know how in SwiftUI to show two different "a" and "b".

It seems like if I use var again, it will deny it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var a=Int.random(in:80...90)
    var b=Int.random(in:60...70)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text ("\(a)+\(b)=")
            Text ("\(a)+\(b)=")

            }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the desired output for your code

Comment: desired output is like 89+62, 81+63, 89+65, may be ten different equations, and I will also put conditions to make when "a" will be 89 or 81. So I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text ("\(Int.random(in:80...90))+\(Int.random(in:80...90))=")

        Text ("\(Int.random(in:80...90))+\(Int.random(in:80...90))=")


    }
}
```

}
If you use the same `var a` and `var b` for both text fields the same numbers will always appear regardless of how many times you run  `Int.random`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there another way to do it as in Xcode that "a" and "b" can change when run any times? because I will add more complex conditions.

Comment: Give us an example of the complex condition etc

Comment: for example, if I want to add text like "a"-"b", I will also put a condition like if a>b , or I can add another var "c" to make a new equation "a"+"b"-"c", and more conditions like if c< a+b etc.